# Why are there different keyboard commands for quitting applications?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Some applications, like evince, won't respond to Ctrl+Q and instead require Ctrl+W. Other applications, like Movie Player, won't respond to Ctrl+W, and instead require Ctrl+Q. Why is this? Are there plans to standardize this behavior across ubuntu (at least the applications that come with the standard install)?

Answer (score 1):

That is generally because those are application specific short-cuts.

You can use `Alt + F4` for all applications, since that is a system short-cut.